# AWS STL_LOAD_ERRORS not loading, receiving error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to look at the error messages after trying to COPY S3 files into Redshift.

Using this:

```
SELECT * FROM stl_load_errors;
```

Error message returning:

Query result is not ready, status: FINISHED (Service: AmazonRedshift; Status Code: 400; Error Code: QueryNotFinished; Request ID: 71e1d849-29ac-4e18-8746-2a25f71e67c7; Proxy: null)

Never seen this before.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you connecting to Redshift?  This looks to be an HTTP error (400), not a JDBC or ODBC error.  Are you using the new API based query mechanism?  Are you using the web based workbench in the AWS Redshift console?  More information on how you are connecting will likely lead to the source of your issue.